# TFS (Preview) build failes due to missing assembly?

Tags: tfs

I'm new to TFS and trying to do my first automatic build through the hosted TFS (tfspreview.com) but it fails due to a missing assembly.

One of my projects in the solution references Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration. The reference has `Copy Local` set to `True` but it seems like it doesn't exist/isn't found by the TFS.

How do I tell TFS where to find the assembly?

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1561): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=1.7.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the
>   assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code,
>   you may get compilation errors.

Comment: Often times the reference won't be reflected in the solution file which will cause this error. I solved a similar problem before leaving work today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer in [Using NuGet with TFS Build Automation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/05/10/using-nuget-with-tfs-build-automation.aspx). It failed because I've added the reference through NuGet.

This is needed to make it work:

1. Right click on the Solution in Solution Explorer
2. Click on “Enable NuGet Package Restore”
3. Click “Yes” when prompted

The blog has a lot more information so have a look for a complete fix with explanations.

Comment: One other thing to remember is that you need to make sure that you are referencing the WindowsAzure DLLs in your project via NuGet and not the local install of the SDK.  Thanks for the solution!